# how to run app scripts on mobile, there is one script working another not working

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have to use a mobile while I am traveling for managing google sheets.
I have two functions which I have assigned to buttons it is working. however, it doesn't work in mobile version.
for this, I have found a why by filling a checkbox in a cell with `onEdit` function.
but one function is working while another is not working even in desktop version when I click a checkbox

```
function onEdit(e){
const rg = e.range;
if(rg.getA1Notation() === "C30" && rg.isChecked() && rg.getSheet().getName() === "pad no 1"){
loopThroughQuantity();  //loopThroughQuantity is a function name
rg.uncheck();
}
}
```

now I have two functions the one is working correctly both in mobile and desktop version of google sheets however another function is not working both in desktop and mobile version through the checkbox
the first function is below which is working

```
function loopThroughQuantity(){
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var bill = ss.getSheetByName("pad no 1");
var billdata=bill.getRange(8, 1, 27, 6).getValues();
var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("stock");
var range = sheet.getDataRange();
var stock = range.getValues();
for (var i=0; i<billdata.length;i++){
var q = billdata[i][5];
var desc = billdata[i][1];
    for( var j=0; j<stock.length; j++ ) {
      if( stock[j][0] === desc ) {
        range.offset(j,2,1,1).setValue(q);
      }
    }
  }
 }
```

while the other code is below which is not working through clicking a checkbox

```
function runBothfunctions(){
//function 1
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()
var ss1 = ss.getSheetByName('pad no 1')
var ss1Id = ss1.getSheetId()
var ss2 = ss.getSheetByName('bill list')
var ssId = ss.getId()
var clientName = ss1.getRange(3,3).getValue()
var invoiceNumber = ss1.getRange(4,3).getValue()
var totalBill = ss1.getRange(29,9).getValue()
var d = new Date();
var fullDate = ('0' + d.getDate()).slice(-2) +"/"+ ('0' + (d.getMonth() +1)).slice(-2) +"/"+ 
(d.getYear().toString()).slice(-2)
var invoiceFileName = invoiceNumber + '_' + fullDate + '_' + clientName +'_'+ totalBill

var url = ss.getUrl()
url = url.replace(/edit$/,'')
var url_ext = 'export?exportFormat=pdf&format=pdf'
+ '&size=A4'                           // paper size: "legal" / "letter" / "A4"
+ '&fitw=true'                         // fit to width, false for actual size
+ '&sheetnames=false&printtitle=false' // hide optional headers and footers
+ '&gridlines=false'                   // hide gridlines
+ '&gid=' + ss1Id                      // the sheet's Id

var token = ScriptApp.getOAuthToken()  
// Convert sheet1 to PDF
var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url + url_ext, { headers: { 'Authorization': 'Bearer ' +  token }})

var blob = response.getBlob().setName(invoiceFileName + '.pdf')  
// Add the folder ID of the Drive folder where the PDF should be saved. Create a folder and copy this 
ID: www.goo.gl/TfgqrN
var invoiceURL = 
DriveApp.getFolderById('1I8NvoAERa_NxgS3z5jmYCC8TOlejDHNT').createFile(blob).getUrl()
ss2.getRange(ss2.getLastRow() +1, 1).setFormula('=HYPERLINK("' + invoiceURL + '";"' + invoiceFileName 
+ '")')

var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var sheet = ss.getSheets()[0];

var lastRow = sheet.getLastRow();
var lastColumn = sheet.getLastColumn();

//create an array of the invoice numbers already created 
var colArray = sheet.getRange(4, 3).getValues();

//sort the array values to find max
var maxInColumn = colArray.sort(function(a,b){return b-a})[0][0];

var nextCell = sheet.getRange(4, 3);

//assign the max+1 to the next entry
nextCell.setValue(maxInColumn+1);

var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var sheet = ss.getSheetByName('Unwanted Sheet');

DriveApp.createFile(ss.getBlob());

//function 2
 var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('pad no 1');
sheet.getRange('B8:F28').clearContent();
sheet.getRange('h8:h28').clearContent();
sheet.getRange('C3').clearContent();




//function 3
//below code is for subtracting sold quantity from old quantity
var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('stock');

var maxRows = sheet.getMaxRows();

var soldRange = sheet.getRange(2, 3, maxRows); // row, column, number of rows
var totalRange = sheet.getRange(2, 2, maxRows);

var soldValues = soldRange.getValues();
var totalValues = totalRange.getValues();
for (var row in soldValues) {
var soldCellData = soldValues[row][0];
var totalCellData = totalValues[row][0];

if (soldCellData !== "" && totalCellData !== "") {
  totalValues[row][0] = totalCellData - soldCellData;
  soldValues[row][0] = "";
 } 
}

soldRange.setValues(soldValues);
totalRange.setValues(totalValues);


var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('pad no 1');
sheet.getRange('c3').setValue('Make Your Next Bill');
 //sheet.getRange('c3').activate();  


//function 4
//var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi()
//var response = ui.alert('bill saved and cleared  ');


}
```

this code works correctly by clicking an image separately but does not work with onEdit.
maybe the code is too long. 
one thing I add it more here. if it starts working by clicking the checkbox, how to run both functions at one on mobile, do I need to combine these two functions and run it by clicking one checkbox It will be great if these two functions start work with one click.
thanks in advance for giving me more time.

Comment: I don’t see where you’re running both functions in the onEdit. Time is critical in these as they will terminate after 30 seconds

Comment: It runs when i assign it to a button

Comment: If there are restrictions to onEdit functions then how can i run it on mobile, may i break the function into 3 or 4 functions to remove the problem of time and size?

Comment: the function    'runbothfuction',    i separated the code for different functions inside, I have come to know there is only one function not working which is function no 1 which saved my bill as pdf

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that you are overloading your `onEdit(e)` function.

Take a look on [Simple Triggers restrictions](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers#restrictions)

> Script executions and API requests do not cause triggers to run.

which is your case

> They cannot access services that require authorization.

which is your case too

This is the reason why `onEdit(e)` is not working.